# javascript local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

How do you check if a local storage value is blank?  for example..

```
localStorage.setItem('favoriteflavor','');

var taste = localStorage.getItem('favoriteflavor');

if(taste == null){
   console.log('favoriteflavor is null');
} 
else {
   console.log('favoriteflavor is NOT null');
}
```

This make the most sense but I am not getting any results.  I have also tried this..

```
 if(localStorage['favoriteflavor'] == 'null'){ 
   console.log('favoriteflavor is null');
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AwsyE/6/

Comment: You set the value as `''`, so compare against that. Use `if (taste == '')`

Comment: `null` and empty string `''` are different, so they are no comparable in the way you are trying.

Comment: May be worth noting, `getItem` **does** return `null` but only in the instance **the key doesn't exist**. If key exists, it will return `''` or a string. To remove a key/val pair you should use `removeItem`. [MDN ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#Storage) doesn't seem to list methods in detail.

Answer (score 4):

If you set `favoriteflavor` to an empty string, then you should check it for an empty string not something else

```
localStorage.setItem('favoriteflavor','');
var taste = localStorage.getItem('favoriteflavor');
if(taste == ''){
   console.log('favoriteflavor is empty');    
}
else{
   console.log('favoriteflavor is NOT empty');
}
```

Alternatively if you were removing `favoriteflavor` then you could check it against null

```
localStorage.setItem('favoriteflavor','chocolate');
delete localStorage['favoriteflavor'];
// or use localStorage.removeItem('favoriteflavor');

var taste = localStorage.getItem('favoriteflavor');

if(taste == null){

   console.log('favoriteflavor is null');

}
else
{
   console.log('favoriteflavor is NOT null');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/AwsyE/10/

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your item as '' right here:

```
localStorage.setItem('favoritefla','');
```

and Testing if the output is == null

```
if(localStorage['favoriteflavor'] == 'null'
```

When it's equals to '' since you yourself already set this value previously.

I believe you are trying to know if the browser has `localStorage` capacity which you can do by testing if you can insert and remove items from this object, like the following:

```
var hasStorage = (function() {
  try {
    localStorage.setItem(mod, mod);
    localStorage.removeItem(mod);
    return true;
  } catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
}());
```

The function above will return true if the broswer has localStorage capacity. I hope it helped, cheers